# PHP Quiz game with score keeping

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an application that needs to be able to grab questions from a MySQL database and display them to the user. The user should then be able to answer and submit. At the end of the quiz it should display the user's score. How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is such a common task that you can easily find the code and a tutorial on the net. Just Google "php mysql quiz".

Comment: In fact, "The Absolute Beginners Guide" series book on PHP should have this code available.